# Oracle Weblogic Tutorial

Tags: weblogic

I am busy working through the Oracle Weblogic tutorial, setting up WebLogic on my local machine, creating servers and machines, as well as nodes. I am stuck at setting up the machines to connect to the nodeManger. I am running Linux Cinnamon Mint 19 and have had no problems setting up and running the Admin server.

The machines are set up to look at localhost, port 5556.

Version: WebLogic Server 14.1.1.0.0

I have followed the steps in the tutorial.

The log in the NodeManager gives the following config:

````
Configuration settings:

LogAppend=true
AuthenticationEnabled=true
CrashRecoveryEnabled=false
LogLimit=0
weblogic.StopScriptEnabled=false
DomainsDirRemoteSharingEnabled=false
DomainsFileEnabled=true
weblogic.StartScriptName=startWebLogic.sh
DomainsFile=/home/timl/Development/scratch/u01/user_projects/domains/base_domain/nodemanager/nodemanager.domains
ListenPort=5556
LogLevel=INFO
weblogic.StartScriptEnabled=true
LogFile=/home/timl/Development/scratch/u01/user_projects/domains/base_domain/nodemanager/nodemanager.log
LogToStderr=true
NativeVersionEnabled=true
ProcessDestroyTimeout=20000
SecureListener=true
ListenBacklog=50
LogFormatter=weblogic.nodemanager.server.LogFormatter
ListenAddress=localhost
StateCheckInterval=500
coherence.StartScriptEnabled=false
LogCount=1
NodeManagerHome=/home/timl/Development/scratch/u01/user_projects/domains/base_domain/nodemanager
RestEnabled=false
isLogLockingEnabled=true
weblogic.startup.JavaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle
weblogic.startup.MW_Home=
coherence.startup.JavaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle
coherence.startup.MW_Home=

Domain name mappings:

base_domain -> /home/timl/Development/scratch/u01/user_projects/domains/base_domain

<17 Sep 2020 10:32:46 South Africa Standard Time> <INFO> <14.1.1.0.0>
<17 Sep 2020 10:32:46 South Africa Standard Time> <INFO> <Server Implementation Class: weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServer$ClassicServer.>
<17 Sep 2020 10:32:46 South Africa Standard Time> <INFO> <Secure socket listener started on port 5556, host localhost/127.0.0.1>```

The Machines are set for the listen address to locahost, on port 5556

The only thing I can see in the server logs is this:


```<17 Sep 2020, 10:31:18,663 South Africa Standard Time> <Notice> <JMX> <BEA-149535> <JMX Resiliency Activity Server=server1 : Attempting to connect to the server during initialization > 
<17 Sep 2020, 10:31:18,663 South Africa Standard Time> <Notice> <JMX> <BEA-149535> <JMX Resiliency Activity Server=server1 : Starting JMX connection. forceReconnect value: false> 
<17 Sep 2020, 10:31:18,663 South Africa Standard Time> <Warning> <JMX> <BEA-149505> <The Administration Server was unable to establish JMX Connectivity with the server1 at the JMX Service URL of <none>.> 
<17 Sep 2020, 10:31:18,663 South Africa Standard Time> <Notice> <JMX> <BEA-149535> <JMX Resiliency Activity Server=server1 : No URL found for the server during the initialization> 
<17 Sep 2020, 10:31:18,663 South Africa Standard Time> <Notice> <JMX> <BEA-149535> <JMX Resiliency Activity Server=server2 : Attempting to connect to the server during initialization > 
<17 Sep 2020, 10:31:18,664 South Africa Standard Time> <Notice> <JMX> <BEA-149535> <JMX Resiliency Activity Server=server2 : Starting JMX connection. forceReconnect value: false> 
<17 Sep 2020, 10:31:18,664 South Africa Standard Time> <Warning> <JMX> <BEA-149505> <The Administration Server was unable to establish JMX Connectivity with the server2 at the JMX Service URL of <none>.> 
<17 Sep 2020, 10:31:18,664 South Africa Standard Time> <Notice> <JMX> <BEA-149535> <JMX Resiliency Activity Server=server2 : No URL found for the server during the initialization> 
<17 Sep 2020, 10:31:18,664 South Africa Standard Time> <Notice> <JMX> <BEA-149535> <JMX Resiliency Activity Server=server3 : Attempting to connect to the server during initialization > 
<17 Sep 2020, 10:31:18,664 South Africa Standard Time> <Notice> <JMX> <BEA-149535> <JMX Resiliency Activity Server=server3 : Starting JMX connection. forceReconnect value: false> 
<17 Sep 2020, 10:31:18,664 South Africa Standard Time> <Warning> <JMX> <BEA-149505> <The Administration Server was unable to establish JMX Connectivity with the server3 at the JMX Service URL of <none>.> 
<17 Sep 2020, 10:31:18,664 South Africa Standard Time> <Notice> <JMX> <BEA-149535> <JMX Resiliency Activity Server=server3 : No URL found for the server during the initialization>```
````

Comment: have you checked firewall rules?

Comment: Did you check nodemanager logs ? Did you try using plain socket connection instead of secured connection ?

Comment: Your domain has N machines, you'll need one NM per machine. For the NM log file you just showed, that NM is listening on localhost on port 5556. So in the WLS console > machines, the machine where the admin server is running should be configured to point to the same machine. Now, are you getting a specific error? What's your current configuration?